# Prove that $T_n$ satisfy $ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{T_i(x_k)T_j(x_k)} = \begin{cases} 0 &: i\ne j \\ l\neq 0 &: i=j \end{cases} \,\! $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

The *Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind* satisfy the recurrence relation
$$
\begin{cases}
T_{n}(x)=2xT_{n-1}(x)-T_{n-2}(x) \qquad n \geq 2 \\
T_{0}(x)=1, \ \ T_{1}(x)=x \\
\end{cases}
$$
The polynomials $T_n(x)$ are orthogonal with respect to the weight function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ defined on $x\in[-1,1]$. This means that 
$$\int_{-1}^1 T_n(x)T_m(x)\,\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=
\begin{cases}
0 &: n\ne m \\
l\neq 0 &: n=m
\end{cases}
$$
Prove that $T_n$ also satisfy a discrete orthogonality condition
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{T_i(x_k)T_j(x_k)} =
\begin{cases}
0 &: i\ne j \\
l\neq 0 &: i=j
\end{cases} \,\!
$$
where the $x_k$ are the $N$ Chebyshev nodes of $T_N(x)$: 
$$x_k=\cos\left(\pi \frac{2k+1}{2N}\right), \ \ k=0,...,N-1$$
For continuous case it should be very simple, by letting $x = \cos (\theta)$ and using the defining identity $T_n(\cos (\theta)) = \cos (n\theta)$. But I can't imagine a way to prove the statement in the discrete case.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: If I understand correctly, there should, I think, be some restriction relating $N,i,j$...? Otherwise try $i=0, j=2, N=1$.

Comment: @Sharkos, thank you for your comment. I've edited my post.

Comment: Thanks; but that wasn't actually what I meant -- your restriction doesn't relate $i,j$ to $N$ at all. Notice that $i=0,j=2,N=1$ gives rise to only one node, $x_k = 0$, but $T_0(0) = 1$ and $T_2(0) = -1$ so the sum is $-1 \neq 0$ and your statement to be proved is false. Hence I think there is some criterion on what $i,j,N$ can be chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: use the formula:
$$ \cos(ix)\cos(jx) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos((i+j)x)+\cos((i-j)x)\right)$$
and consider that:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\cos(kx) = \text{Re} \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(e^{ix}\right)^k. $$